# sending arguments to django rest framework mixin is not parsed as keyword

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am using Django rest framework. I am testing my method via postman.

I have a view called ActionView, which in I'm using a mixin:

```
class ActionView(
             mixins.CreateModelMixin,
             mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
             generics.GenericAPIView):
queryset = Action.objects.all()
serializer_class = ActionSerializer


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The URLs are:

```
urlpatterns = [
path(r'action/', views.ActionView.as_view()),
path(r'alert/', views.AlertView.as_view()),
```

]

and they are included in the main router function.

I am trying to send a get request, like this:

http://localhost:8000/actionsAndAlerts/action/?pk=1/
and like this: http://localhost:8000/actionsAndAlerts/action/?1/

but the pk I am sending is not rendered as a keyword at the get method - and so I keep getting this error: AssertionError: Expected view ActionView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

I tried adding: @detail_route(url_path='action/(?P[0-9]+)') above the get method but with no success.

any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `?` before url arg, just use `http://localhost:8000/actionsAndAlerts/action/1/`. But you need to add to urlpattern `pk` argument (see details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)) to make it's possible for view to select correct object to display, change pattern to this:

```
path('action/<int:pk>', views.ActionView.as_view()),
```

Comment: I am getting a page not found error , but ill try to keep going this way